# KnockoutJS - bootstrap 3 modal binding doesn't working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have a Bootstrap modal div:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalLoginData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Login Data</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <label class="sr-only">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" data-bind="value: username" />
            </div>   

            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <label class="sr-only">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" data-bind="value: password"  />
            </div>   

            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <label class="sr-only">Repeat your password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Repeat your password" data-bind="value: repeatedPassword" />
            </div>   
            <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <label class="sr-only">Login</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-bind="click: confirmLoginData">Confirm</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal" data-bind="click: cancelLoginData">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm opening this modal through JS.

Ok, if I set the username property with some value...

```
function Model() {
    this.username = ko.observable("kiwanax");
}
```

... the value is properly displayed on a span element **outside** that modal div...

```
<span data-bind="text: username"></span>
```

... but isn't working on that textbox in the modal div above.

Anyone knows what's happening?

Thanks!

Comment: post the JS code that is "opening this modal".  And maybe the viewmodel.

Comment: A jsfiddle showing the problem would be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, posting a more complete version of your code would go a long ways in enabling others to help you. Without posting the javascript you have written, people can only make guesses at what you are doing.

That being said, here is an example of your modal where knockout does display the **username** inside the modal as well as outside the modal.

http://jsbin.com/AFORuzAT/2/edit

```
$('#modalLoginData').modal();

function Model() {
    this.username = ko.observable("kiwanax");
    this.password = ko.observable();
    this.repeatedPassword = ko.observable();
    this.cancelLoginData = function () {
        console.log( 'cancel!' );
    };
    this.confirmLoginData = function () {
         console.log( 'confirm login data!' );
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new Model());
```